# How to get a list of 'get' properties?

Tags: javascript, properties

Say I have some object:

```
Org.prototype = {
 constructor  : Org,
 get id(){ return this._id; },
 some_method: function(){},
 etc...
```

How to retrieve getters of the object?

Comment: You would need to retrieve the property descriptors and check which ones have a `get` property.

Comment: You should fix your question, so instead of saying "have `get` prefix`, it says "have getters defined" (which is what I think you meant). The way it reads now confused at least one person answering.

Comment: @torazaburo i fixed the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all the property names, and filter down to only those whose property descriptor has a `get` property.

```js
function Foo() { }

Foo.prototype = { 
  get id() { return this._id; },
  otherfunc() { }
};

function getGetters(obj) {
  var proto = obj.prototype;

  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)
    .filter(name => Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, name).get);
}
    
console.log(getGetters(Foo));
```

Comment: Possibly also traverse the prototype chain if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of properties which have "getter" function use the following approch with `Object.keys`, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and `Array.filter` functions:

```js
function Org(){};

Org.prototype = {
    constructor  : Org,
    get id(){ return this._id; },
    some_method: function(){}
};

propList = Object.keys(Org.prototype).filter(function (p) {
    return typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Org.prototype, p)['get'] === "function"
});

console.log(propList);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor

Comment: Unless I'm sorely mistaken, the `get` property on a property descriptor will **always** be a function.

Comment: @torazaburo, certainly, but only if `get` exists within property descriptor. Otherwise, `typeof undefined === 'function'`